# I want to run this jquery on load not how it is, how should I enter the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have this code that runs when someone clicks yes

```
<a id="question-submit" class="cta cta-submit corners" onclick="jQuery(&#39;#user-process&#39;).modal(&#39;show&#39;);">
    <span>Yes »</span>
</a>
```

I want it to run when page is loaded as if they clicked yes.....How would I do this, I can't figure it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() { 
        jQuery('#user-process').modal('show');
    })
</script>
```

jQuery() adds an on-load event.